# How do I extract the particular row from .csv file and write out in to another file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, anaconda

I have .csv file something like this:

```
x,   y,   z  
1,  10,   45 
2,   0,   34
4,  15,   34
5,  99,   38
6,  13,   23
5,  99,   38
6,  13,   23
.    .     .
1000, 234, 678
```

now I would like to write out the rows of column x, which can be advisable by 5 form this .csv file.

Here is the more detail about the file:

```
x,                  y
0.0000123219872323, 1.213
.                     .
4.991414887967266,  8.123
4.996324047550014,  2.323
5.000581861276573,  6.234
5.006295444400881,  9.234
5.029657671211434,  1.219
5.034806828096650,  1.123
.                   .
9.997414351064347,  1.345
10.00211537343025,  1.232
10.00675672507283,  2.234
10.01201110041457,  1.003
.                   .
```

Here is the real file that I want to process. I have to extract the rows from this .csv file. In particular, rows of the column values which can be dividable by 5.

My output should look like this:

```
5.000581861276573,  6.234
10.00211537343025,  1.232
```

Not twice the values of 5, 10 and so on. Once one 5 value is extracted, 
it should go to next divisible by 5, in this case it should be 10.

Comment: You want to sample every 5 rows, starting from the first, stopping at the 1000th, and write that to another file?

Comment: If your `x` column is really floating point as there, then you will rarely if ever truly find multiples of 5, unless you mean "within a 1% tolerance" (in which case you need to specify that). (BTW: I'm inferring "divisable" vice "advisable".) Regardless, if you ask this (or similar) question again, I suggest you add code that you've actually tried; SO is not meant to be a "write this for me for free" service, so it helps to show what efforts you've tried. It also suggests further context for your intended process.

Comment: Why do you want to include  `5.000581861276573` but not `5.006295444400881`?

Comment: Manu!: Its just example, and yes, I just want to include the value which is first floor value which is closer to 5.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write out each 5th row you can simply do

```
df.iloc[::5, :].to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

whereby `df` is a pandas dataframe created like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
```

Otherwise, you can also do

```
# define all indexes here
out_rows = [1, 5]

df.iloc[out_rows, :].to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

You need to specify in more detail what exactly you want to achieve, then we can help better.

EDIT:

As far as I understand now, you want to select based on floats close to certain values. This might be a bit hacky and also assumes that you don't leave out integers (which seems to be a reasonable assumption based on your description of the values):

Let's say your `df` looks like this (replace by actual data):

```
          x,  y
0   0.955425  1
1   0.602229  2
2   1.520194  6
3   1.748095  1
4   2.422760  0
5   2.051359  6
6   3.268572  9
7   3.981412  1
8   4.687532  0
9   4.215138  8
10  5.029877  7
11  5.197888  7
12  6.795040  1
13  6.452637  0
14  7.413032  8
15  7.127841  5
16  8.597014  7
17  8.002060  8
18  9.713273  3
19  9.912318  7
```

As written, first sort the values according to `x,`

```
df = df.sort_values('x,')

          x,  y
1   0.602229  2
0   0.955425  1
2   1.520194  6
3   1.748095  1
5   2.051359  6
4   2.422760  0
6   3.268572  9
7   3.981412  1
9   4.215138  8
8   4.687532  0
10  5.029877  7
11  5.197888  7
13  6.452637  0
12  6.795040  1
15  7.127841  5
14  7.413032  8
17  8.002060  8
16  8.597014  7
18  9.713273  3
19  9.912318  7
```

Then add a helper column where you `floor` the values in `x,`

```
df['helper'] = df['x,'].apply(np.floor).astype(int)

          x,  y  helper
1   0.602229  2       0
0   0.955425  1       0
2   1.520194  6       1
3   1.748095  1       1
5   2.051359  6       2
4   2.422760  0       2
6   3.268572  9       3
7   3.981412  1       3
9   4.215138  8       4
8   4.687532  0       4
10  5.029877  7       5
11  5.197888  7       5
13  6.452637  0       6
12  6.795040  1       6
15  7.127841  5       7
14  7.413032  8       7
17  8.002060  8       8
16  8.597014  7       8
18  9.713273  3       9
19  9.912318  7       9
```

Now drop the duplicates in `helper`:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('helper')

          x,  y  helper
1   0.602229  2       0
2   1.520194  6       1
5   2.051359  6       2
6   3.268572  9       3
9   4.215138  8       4
10  5.029877  7       5
13  6.452637  0       6
15  7.127841  5       7
17  8.002060  8       8
18  9.713273  3       9
```

and export the solution:

```
df.iloc[::5, :].drop('helper', axis=1)

          x,  y
1   0.602229  2
10  5.029877  7
```

Comment: Thanks! what if I column is in float value not in int.

Comment: @Mathi: I don't understand your question. I thought it is about selecting rows not columns? I assumed you are talking about indexes; what do you man by floats in this context or do I misunderstand?

Comment: my first column values starting from 0 and it will grow to N by adding 0.001 (something like that). In the column I need to extract the row at least closer to 5, 10, 15, 20 and so on. How do I do that ?

Comment: It is not working and I am getting some error.

Comment: @Mathi: What error? Make sure you use the correct column names...

Comment: import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('infile.csv')
df = df.sort_values('x,')  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list_1.py", line 3, in <module>

Comment: @Mathi That's not an error message but if it fails then your column name is probably not `x,` but something else (e.g. `time`)... not clear from your question.

Comment: Cleb!: I have edited my question now more precises way, could you please help me now.

Comment: @Mathi: See edit 2. If you still get an error, then there is something going on with your column names, I think

Comment: Cleb!: Thanks this is what I want, but the export solution should be based on the helper column not index!, so I need helper value rows of 5, 10, 15, incrementing by 5.

Comment: @Mathi: That's why `iloc` is used and not `loc`; this solution should do what you described. If you look carefully, you will see that helper is an index from 0-N (that's why it is important that no value is skipped, otherwise it would not work but from your description there is no skipping)

Comment: Cleb!: It makes  a sense, I will do the test and make it right your comments and help. Again thanks a lot!

Comment: Cleb!: this sort function does not seems to work!. import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_2.csv')
df = df.sort_values('x,'). It give me some error!

Comment: @Mathi: That's something I cannot solve for you. Check your column names, whether the import is correct etc. It is a standard function, if it does not work, something is wrong with you data (as written above, your column name is probably not `x,` but e.g. `time`).

Comment: Cleb!: Thanks! should it be just [x] instead of [x,]

Comment: Cleb!: it does not work, I am just using the same file, as you have tried it above. import math
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_2.csv')
df['helper'] = df['x'].apply(np.floor).astype(int)
df = df.drop_duplicates('helper')
df.iloc[::5, :].to_csv('file_3.csv').

Comment: @Mathi: I am afraid that I cannot help you much further at this state; all I posted above works perfectly fine for me, now it is your task to sort your data, print intermediate steps and figure out what goes wrong. Good luck!

Comment: @Mathi: Still does not work? If so, can you edit your question based on what you tried? If it does and you used my answer please consider accepting it and/or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is very broad and needs more explanation. It is also likely that it has been answered in other posts on StackOverflow.

A very basic answer to your question:

```
to_print = [1, 5, 10, 1000]

with open('input_file.csv', 'r') as fr:
    with open('write_here.csv', 'w') as fw:
        for i, row in enumerate(fr):
            if i in to_print:
                 fw.write(row)
```

This simply writes every line that you specify in `to_print` to another csv file.

If you want to print every fifth line between 0 and 1000, you can consider setting `to_print = range(0, 1000, 5)` or, if you don't know the number of lines of your file:

```
with open('input_file.csv', 'r') as fr:
    with open('write_here.csv', 'w') as fw:
        for i, row in enumerate(fr):
            if i % 5 == 0:
                 fw.write(row)
```

Comment: Thanks! could you please tell me how to extract the row closer to 5, 10, 15 when the column values are in float.

Comment: Manu!: I have edited my question now, is it possible for you to help me now.

Answer (score 0):

```
archive_in = open('lines.txt', 'r')
archive_out = open('out.txt', 'w')
i = 0
for line in archive_in.readlines():
    i += 1
    if i == 2:
        archive_out.write(line)
        i = 3
    elif i == 7:
        archive_out.write(line)
        i = 2

archive_in.close()
archive_out.close()
```

EDIT, now write lines with closest values to list inputs.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('lines.txt', header=None)
archive_out = open('out.txt', 'w')
inputs = (1, 5, 10)

for input in inputs:

    archive_out.write(str(df.ix[(df[0] - input).abs().argsort()[:1]].values[0])[1:-1].strip() + '\n')

archive_out.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! I want something like this, could you please tell me how to exactly do when the column values are in float and I need only the rows closer to 5, 10, 15 and so on.

Comment: But then you do not look for the position, look for the value of the variable X

Comment: I guess I need to change those values in the first column into int from the float and extract them as 5,10,15 and so on

Answer (score 0):

crude example using the pandas library which convert the csv into a data-frame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('asdf.csv')
for i in range(200+1):
     df.iloc[i*5]
```

This is assuming you want to go up in 5's

Comment: Thanks! I would like to extract exactly column value closer to 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 and so on.

Comment: Peach!: I have edited my question now, is it possible to help me out now.